# Inequality Constraint Notation

Tags: optimization, notation

I have always seen inequality constraints for optimization problems written as less than or equal to 0 (such as $Ax\leq0$). However, in a book I was reading, throughout they give inequality constraint as being less than or equal to 0 (for example $\mathcal{W}=\left\{w \mid Vw\leq1\right\}$).

I was wondering if there is a reason to write it this way. I get that $Ax-b\leq0$ is the same as $Ax\leq b$ which you could normalize to $Cx\leq 1$. But is there anything more specific being conveyed by writing it this way?

Link to book (purchase link but may be able to access through academic library): [MPC](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-319-24853-0).

Answer (score 1):

The standard form of inequality for MPC is $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\le\mathbf{b}$.

In a special case when $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}$, it turns into $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\le\mathbf{0}$.

The case $\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}\le\mathbf{1}$ is a trivial conversion. Let's assume every $i^{th}$ row of matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is shown by $\mathbf{A}_i$, then

$$\mathbf{C}_i=\frac{\mathbf{A}_i}{b_i}$$
It is possible when no element from $\mathbf{b}$ is equal to zero.

Comment: Super pedantic and not entirely on-topic, but:  you have used `\boldsymbol` extensively in your answer, and it looks quite weird to me.  Perhaps replace it with `\mathbf`, e.g. `\mathbf{Ax} \le \mathbf{b}`, which is rendered as $\mathbf{Ax} \le \mathbf{b}$?  It is a matter of style, but I find `\mathbf` easier to read, and far more aesthetically pleasing...

Comment: @XanderHenderson, thank you for your feedback. Please see the update.

Comment: As I said, it is entirely a matter of style.  If you are satisfied with your post in its current form, then my opinion doesn't really matter---nor did it really matter 24 hours ago, when I first suggested the edit. ;)  That being said, I, personally, prefer this version to the old version.